# In Moodle Certificate not displaying course completion date

Tags: javascript, php, certificate, moodle, moodle-api

I am using Moodle and having problem with the plugin certificate builder I had created my template correctly, but now that learner are starting to complete the course, I've noticed the course completion date is missing from their generated certificates. This date showed up correctly when previewing the certificate. Also if I choose issue date the date will show correctly on the certificate.

[Certificate date setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEwWm.png)

[Certificate Without the completion date when downloading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4cGM.jpg)

share you both images links please check the links below. Currently my moodle version is latest 3.11.5+ and plugin name is Custom certificate for moodle. sharing you the link of the plugin

https://moodle.org/plugins/mod_customcert

Comment: I think you are better off asking the developer of the plugin as this is most likely a bug that you can't fix on your own unless there is a fix in a newer version that you can install. If you at least post all details of what you are using - which plugin exactly, what version, etc. we might be able to tell you if that's the case.

Comment: @feedy thanks for the feedback please check my post i have updated the post added now version and plugin info

Comment: I couldn't find this bug being reported anywhere, but please check this out: https://github.com/mdjnelson/moodle-mod_customcert/issues/383

Perhaps the user you are testing with has not actually completed the course? If that's not the case, you can browse throughout all open issues here or create a new one - you are more likely to receive a solution this way. https://github.com/mdjnelson/moodle-mod_customcert/issues

Answer (score 0):

If you use course completion date you need to allow time for cron to run and generate a course completion date before it can exist to appear on the cert.

You could require learners to complete a feedback form before accessing the cert but don't include the feedback in course completion conditions. Cron can run while the users are occupied with the feedback.

Or you could include an activity grade date in the cert instead of the course completion date, such as a quiz to be passed before receiving the cert. A quiz completion date would be available before the cert is generated.